# adding TextBox Field and Picklist to pdf that send through DocuSignAPI

Tags: docusignapi, visualforce

I have a visualforce page renderAs pdf it uses DocuSign SOAP API to be send. I need to add a testArea field and picklist on the pdf through DocuSign SOAP API.

I found on this link that tab parameters has Text Tab field and List Tab field.

[click here for Tab Parameters](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tab%20Parameters.htm)

how I can write those two fields in the code. My assumption it should be something like this.

```
DocuSignAPI.Tab tab1 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    tab1.Type_x = 'Text';
    tab1.RecipientID = 1;
    tab1.DocumentID = 1;
    tab1.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    tab1.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'bio:';

    envelope.Tabs = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTab();
    envelope.Tabs.Tab = new DocuSignAPI.Tab[1];
    envelope.Tabs.Tab[0] = tab1;
```

when I send it I get this error

Exception - System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in the XML document. ---> Instance validation error: 'Text' is not a valid value for TabTypeCode. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=

Comment: You want to use REST API but getting SOAP error, how is this possible? Are you using SOAP API or REST?

Comment: @AmitKBist Im using SOAP I will update my question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `TextTab`, `type` has to be `Custom` and `CustomTabType` should be `Text`. To Add TextTab and Dropdown, XML will look like below:

```
<ns:Tab>
    <ns:DocumentID>32093411</ns:DocumentID>
    <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
    <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
    <ns:XPosition>124</ns:XPosition>
    <ns:YPosition>261</ns:YPosition>
    <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
    <ns:TabLabel>Text b5a8927a-4f93-4288-b280-d15023b1b834</ns:TabLabel>
    <ns:CustomTabType>Text</ns:CustomTabType>
</ns:Tab>
<ns:Tab>
    <ns:DocumentID>32093411</ns:DocumentID>
    <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
    <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
    <ns:XPosition>349</ns:XPosition>
    <ns:YPosition>261</ns:YPosition>
    <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
    <ns:Name>Red;Blue</ns:Name>
    <ns:TabLabel>Dropdown e7f5ad78-9e10-4339-b342-023a729549b7</ns:TabLabel>
    <ns:CustomTabType>List</ns:CustomTabType>
    <ns:CustomTabListItems>Red;Blue</ns:CustomTabListItems>
    <ns:CustomTabListValues>Red;Blue</ns:CustomTabListValues>
</ns:Tab>
```

Comment: where I can find the xml file or do I have to create one and upload it to brands? im kinda new with docusign

Comment: which XML file you are referring to?

Comment: in your answer above you want me to add the above code to XML. is the XML File there and need to be edit or create new XML file and upload it up

Comment: SOAP works on XML, I don't have class artifacts to write a code. I gave above XML which I tested using SOAPUI, and this will be created by your coding language. You need to use your visualforce classes to create XML.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Amit's answer: If using the DocuSign SOAP Apex SDK, I believe you would want something along the lines of this for the text tab:

```
tab1.Type = "Custom"
tab1.CustomTabType = "Text"
```

The picklist would be:

```
tab2.Type = "Custom"
tab2.CustomTabType = "List"
tab2.Name = "Red;Green;Blue"
```

as lists use a semicolon separated Name value to populate options.